# Evaluate startwith's param when subscribing

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

```
observableEmitingItemsRegularly
.map(this::cacheLastItem) //set the object in lastItem variable
.startWith(lastItem);
```

Returns always the same object at the beginning: The value interpreted at the time that line got interpreted.

I already tried:

Changing

```
.startWith(lastItem);
```

with

```
.startWith(getLastItem());
```

The function `getLastItem()` is called when we initialize the observable, not when we subscribe as I want to.

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `Defer`

From the documentation:

> **Defer** do not create the Observable until the observer subscribes, and
>   create a fresh Observable for each observer

```
.startWith(Observable.defer(() -> Observable.from(getLastItem()));
```